# Software to Index and Document large-number of PDF documents based on certain criteria

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I am not tech savvy at all....at our law firm we have literally tens of thousands of pdf documents that the attorney wants indexed.  When I say indexed, I mean she wants to make a chart and input the bates numbering, the title of the document, and the date of the document.  Is there any such software anywhere that will help with this?  This literally takes us weeks to complete, and so I am searching for someone or something that would help out so we can get more accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the huge number of documents I would strongly advise you to use a full fledged document management system in your company. These systems rely on a database management system to store documents and metadata, they may require some advanced knowledge to install and manage, but the end result is worthy the effort.

In the past I worked with [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/features/cms), which is fully web based, relying on Tomcat and Postgres. It did not manage the database properly (missing foreign keys) and could go into an inconsistent state. This was some years ago, later versions could be more reliable.

I also worked with [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/products/document-management) for a short time, which is a bit more complex, but also more reliable. It is probably the most complete open source solution out there.

Other open source options are [OpenKM](http://www.openkm.com/en/), [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/products/document-management), [OpenDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com/) and [Plone](http://plone.org/), none of which I have ever used.

Depending on your experience managing software systems, you might profit from professional support.